# Word 2007: Quickly restoring default table format on a series of formatted tables

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have applied few formatting styles to all tables in a document. Now I want to restore them to default style. Is there any shortcut to restore all the tables at once? Appreciating your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a shortcut to do that all at once.

However you can select all of them and restyle them through the ribbon (Table tools should be selected).

It's not automatic, but it's fast enough (i mean if there are few tables and not say 100).